# Java threading behaviour on Windows

Tags: java, windows, multithreading

I have some problems using threads in Windows Server 2003.

`main`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
   LogBackWriterRunnable logBackWriterRunnable = new LogBackWriterRunnable(i, logger);
   Thread t = new Thread(logBackWriterRunnable);
   t.start();
}
```

`LogBackWriterRunnable`:

```
public void run() {
    try{
        for(int i = 0; i <=1000;i++){
           logger.info("Info Message from process number -------> " + noProceso + cadenaIdentificadora);
           logger.warn("Error Message from process number -------> " + noProceso + cadenaIdentificadora);
           logger.info("Debug Message from process number -------> " + noProceso + cadenaIdentificadora);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("Excepción ---> "+ e);
    }
}
```

When I excecute the app on Windows XP (using `t.start();` and `t.run();`) I can see diferent behavior (synchronous and asynchronous), everything is perfect.

But when I excecute the same app on Windows Server 2003 ED, I only can see a synchronous behavior.

Comment: How are you defining "synchronous" and "asynchronous"?

Comment: It may be a time slice difference. Have you tried for example with 10,000 or 100,000 iterations in the thread code instead of 1000?

Comment: @skaffman: He probably means that the log output is interleaved in 'asynchronous'.

Comment: If you are keen to see interleaved log output in "start()" , you could add `Thread.sleep(1)` in your run method a few times to force context change (CPU allocation to threads). In "run()" you should still see non-interleaved output.

Answer (score 0):

And the behavior you see is perfectly normal. Add the following to your LogBack...Writer class :

```
static Object syncPoint = new Object();
```

And the run() method:

```
public void run() {
  synchronized(syncPoint){
   try{
    for(int i = 0; i <=1000;i++){
       logger.info("Info Message from process number -------> " + noProceso + cadenaIdentificadora);
       logger.warn("Error Message from process number -------> " + noProceso + cadenaIdentificadora);
       logger.info("Debug Message from process number -------> " + noProceso + cadenaIdentificadora);
    }
   }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("Excepción ---> "+ e);
  }
 }
}
```

[And some interesting lecture for you!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: And how does this explain the difference between the behaviors on the two different version of Windows?

Comment: The order and when a thread yields it's execution should not be important when you develop your application. For example, windows uses time slices (but implementations are different between different versions of windows) and linux uses round-robin for the thread scheduler (this is operating system core scheduler).


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29